# In my case, should I configure my router as a wireless bridge or an AP?

Tags: wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

I have a small LAN in my home office (upstairs) consisting of a wired Netgear ProSafe VPN Firewall (FVS318) serving as the gateway router and DHCP server. Connected to the gateway router are the cable  modem, 2 PC's, a Synology NAS, and a Linksys wireless-N router (WRT300N) serving as an access point for my wireless notebook and iPhone.

I'm going to replace the Netgear ProSafe router, serving as my Internet gateway, with the new Linksys E4200 Dual-band wireless-N router. I'm installing the new Netgear Powerline kit (XAVB5004) consisting of a single-port unit that will be attached to the gateway router (upstairs) and a 4-port gigabit ethernet unit that will be used downstairs to attach an Internet ready HDTV and CD/DVD player to the upstairs LAN.

What I would like to do is take the Linksys wireless-N router (WRT300N) that I no longer need upstairs and also attach it to the 4-port Netgear powerline adaptor downstairs, with the hopes that it will improve the wireless connections to my laptop and iPhone when downstairs.

Should the WRT300N (firmware v1.1, supports DD-WRT) be configured as an AP, repeater, or a wireless bridge?

Answer (score 1):

As the names say, bridges connect multiple networks and access points allow access to a single network.

Thus, what you need is an access point if it's connected to your network.

**Reflecting your edit:** A repeater repeats the signals it receives, which is what you need without network. :)